# Displaying symbol size based on number of records with value in ArcGIS Pro

Tags: arcgis-pro, symbology, count

I am new to working in ArcGIS Pro.

I have a table of historical sites, each with a county location.  I geocoded the table so now I have a point for each county that has at least one historical site.  Now I want to vary my symbol by size based on the number of sites in that county (some only have one and others have up to a dozen), as determined by the number of records (rows) in my table that name that given county.

I thought it'd be something as simple as going with *Single Symbol*, then going to *Vary symbology by attribute* and using the Expression Builder to count instances of the county name/state combo (I used *Count($feature.LongLabel)*), but either that's not the right Function or Field or I've messed something else up.

Seems like it should be straightforward: if four rows in my table are for sites in Alexander County, NC, the symbol centered in that county should be size 4 (for example), and if there are eight rows in my table for sites in Letcher County, KY, the symbol should be size 8.

How would you do it?

---

To be sure, I suddenly realized--duh--that I can do a summarize on my table on the LongLabel field and then join that new layer with my historic site layer, but I think my question still stands: is there a way to do it within the existing table without exporting a summary?

Comment: Join summary table to County table and label it, because you describe County not indiv.points.